# How to replace escape text with other symbols/escape text?

Tags: javascript

So I need replace the escape texts; &gt and &lt in the string to [] and <>
for example

if I have

```
/&/lt;a href=/&/quot;google.com/&/quot;/&/gt; google /&/lt;/a/&/gt;
```

I want to convert that into [< google.com> google] and it will work as a link.

this is my function for escapeText for converting content, which is the text user has entered:

```
var escapeText = function(html) {
    var result = String(html)
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    if (result === '' + html) return html;
    else return result;
}
content = escapeText(content);
```

if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: how to convert the strings into a specific format of [<link> label] where it will still work as a html link

Answer (score 0):

One (rather weird) way to do this is to assign the text to `innerHTML` of a DOM node, and return `innerText`:

```
var p = document.createElement('div');
p.innerHTML = '&lt;a href=&quot;google.com&quot;&gt; google &lt;a&gt;';
console.log(p.innerText);
// "<a href="google.com"> google <a>"
```